# Passing non-static member function as argument to member function

Tags: c++, class, pass-by-reference

I am trying to pass a non-static member function of a class as an argument to another member function that takes a function reference. The code I currently have can be illustrated as:

```
bool someClass::baseFunction( unsigned argument, bool (&argumentFunction)(unsigned) ) const{
    ...
    ... use argumentFunction(argument) somehow...
    ...
}

bool someClass::anotherFunction(unsigned) const{
    ...
}

bool someClass::finalFunction(unsigned argument) const{
    return baseFunction(argument, anotherFunction);
}
```

However this prompts the compiler error

```
"invalid use of non-static member function"
```

, and I understand this is because the function I pass as an argument inside "finalFunction" is non-static. However is there any other way to pass a non-static member function as an argument in the code I have shown here?

Comment: On which object do you want the member function to be called?

Comment: A pointer to a (non-static) member function is *not* the same as a pointer to a non-member function. It should be the same for references even through I honestly don't know about references to function, never have used them (pointers are the usual). Either do as the standard library does and use templates, or use [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) together with either [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) or [lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Comment: Do you need to support any function being passed in, or just other members of `someClass`?

Comment: I only need support for members of "someClass", and I want to pass only the member functions of the object making the call to finalFunction.

Comment: You can't teat non-static member functions as normal functions because they need to be bound to an object.  Either pass a lambda or a std::function

Comment: Could you show in the answer how to do solve this with lambdas or std::function? This would add a lot of clarity and also make it clearer for people checking this thread in the future.

Comment: @W.Verbeke there's plenty of examples around; I'm pretty sure you'll find this is a duplicate if you search hard enough.  I don't have time to write a full answer though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *only* want to use non-static methods of a single class, just change the type of the argument function parameter to a member function pointer

```
bool someClass::baseFunction(unsigned argument,
                             bool (someClass::*argumentFunction)(unsigned))
{
    // use argumentFunction(argument) somehow...
    return (this->*argumentFunction)(argument);
}
```

Note that I've changed `baseFunction` to be non-const, since you have it invoking a non-const member function.

```
bool someClass::finalFunction(unsigned argument){
    return baseFunction(argument, &someClass::anotherFunction);
}
```

Comment: In my code all functions were const, I forgot to add it for the 2 last functions in my questions, I fixed the question now.

Comment: I also wonder, is there a way to do what you show here with a reference to a member function? Or is it only possible with a pointer?

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to call the member function on the same object as the calling member function's object, then a simple pointer-to-member should do the trick:

```
bool someClass::anotherFunction(unsigned int) { /* ... */ }

bool someClass::baseFunction(
    unsigned int argument,
    bool (someClass::* mf)(unsigned int) const) const {
  return (this->*mf)(argument);
}

bool someClass::finalFunction(unsigned argument) {
  return baseFunction(argument, &someClass::anotherFunction);
}
```

Comment: Argh, you beat me to it. Although, I think your const-qualification is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve desired functionality would be to use `std::function` instead of the member function pointer. It would like something like this:

```
bool someClass::baseFunction(unsigned argument, std::function<bool (unsigned) const> argumentFunction) const {
    argumentFunction(argument);
}

bool someClass::anotherFunction(unsigned){
    /// ...
}

bool someClass::finalFunction(unsigned argument) {
    return baseFunction(argument, [this](unsigned arg){ this->anotherFunction(arg); });
}
```

Note, that in your case, argument is always the same, so you can capture it as well in lambda and do not pass `argument` into `baseFunction` at all.